# The urllb3.excpetions.Location Parse Error

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I have been trying to automate WhatsApp with selenium but I'm having trouble to parse .here's my code below

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager import chrome
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
Import random
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

chrome = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
chrome.get("https://web.whatsapp.com")
```

Comment: Where is your code attempting to "parse"?

Comment: Is Failed to parse : http//127.0.0.1:49011/session